# SystemD Unit File Documentation Error

Tags: systemd

I want to create a SystemD Unit file, and use the documentation option to reference a text file I created. However each time I use the `systemctl help test1.service` command (as root), I get an error.  To illustrate this problem, I have made an example:

Here is the script I will enable in a SystemD Unit for testing purposes :

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ cat ~/test.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello"
```

Here is the documentation file I will reference in the SystemD Unit:

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ cat ~/test.txt

this is a piece of test documentation
```

Here is the System D Unit file :

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/systemd/system/test1.service 

[Unit]
Description=Test
Documentation=file://localhost/home/centos/test.txt

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/centos/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now to activate my unit file, and try to see the documentation associated with that unit :

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
[centos@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl restart test1.service 
[centos@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status test1.service 
● test1.service - Test
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test1.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2019-02-17 18:37:13 GMT; 6s ago
     Docs: file://localhost/home/centos/test.txt
  Process: 16036 ExecStart=/home/centos/test.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16036 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 17 18:37:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Test.
Feb 17 18:37:13 localhost.localdomain test.sh[16036]: hello
```

Here is the problem :

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ systemctl help test1.service 
Can't show: file://localhost/home/centos/test.txt
```

I initially thought this was a naming convention for `file`. But having read the documentation, I should be able to use (and have tested) these three formats (each time restarting the `systemd` daemon, and restarting the service):

```
file://localhost/home/centos/test.txt
file:///home/centos/test.txt
file:/home/centos/test.txt
```

But Each time I get the same error when I try and view the documentation for my unit with the `systemd` help command.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `systemctl help` is basically "if it's a man uri show it, otherwise say you can't show it":

```c
        STRV_FOREACH(p, i->documentation)
                if (startswith(*p, "man:"))
                        show_man_page(*p + 4, false);
                else
                        log_info("Can't show: %s", *p);
```

(from
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L4643
)